# USB Security by Encrypt.com - where do i purchase this ap? (The instructions say it has never been hacked?)

Tags: boot, usb, password, encryption

I have a Lexar usb stick with Encrypt technology. Lexar said I had to purchase for like $12.99 software to use the USB stick, as it is so good apparently that it has never been hacked according to their usb contained manual. Is lexar the only place to dowload this password to open usb stick technology? Why doesn't Cannonical sell this?

Comment: No need, just use https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystemsOnRemovableStorage on a regular USB drive.

Answer (score 2):

The software you are mentioning isn't safer than the one built into Ubuntu. No need to purchase anything special. The software you are talking about uses "256-bit AES encryption" according to their website.

You can have an encryption using the same algorithm using the "cryptsetup" on Ubuntu with a regular thumb drive, see for example: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedFilesystemsOnRemovableStorage

There is also a graphical frontend for this built into the "gnome-disk-utility". Have a look at [this graphical tutorial](http://computing.help.inf.ed.ac.uk/linux-secure-usb-sticks), for example.

Be aware that by using encryption technology on a thumb drive you will likely lose interoperability. This applies to the "cryptsetup" solution I'm proposing here (it will work out-of-the-box on Ubuntu and most other distros, but not on Windows) and *even more* to vendor-specific solutions like the Lexar software!

Comment: FYI, `cryptsetup` supports the TrueCrypt format too